# how to handling CORS over $http in Angularjs1.3

Tags: angularjs, cors

Does anyone know how to come over cross-domain-access on Angularjs 1.3?
I have tried following, but it seems not working properly.
The problem is there is no a single article from Angularjs regarding this issue.

```
app.config([
    "$httpProvider",
    function($httpProvider){
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*';
    }
]);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why kind of request are you trying to make? Is it a GET/POST? try using a rest client to verify your serverside api.

Comment: I am using a GET request to may node.js/express.js server.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a client side change. You need to update the server where the api is and add a header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to allow Cors requests:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Comment: Can you verify that the header is being returned by the server when you do a request.

Comment: My server API has the setting like: `app.use(function(req, res) {res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');})`, but seems the error on client comes very soon before the server responses are coming.

Comment: Try to add more CORS header like //   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
//   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS');
//   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Cookie'); this is on your server-side from where your client is requesting

Comment: I did the setting both in Angularjs client and expressjs proxy, but the result was some error on chrome with message "Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Headers is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers".